# Haskell: ctags (and Kate editor)

Tags: haskell, text-editor, ctags, kate

I tried CTags plugin for Kate editor. It kinda works, index builds silently (no error messages), database file along with the necessary menu entries appears. Then `Go to definition` - `No hits found`.

I am not surprised too much. Apparently, Kate builds the index this way:

```
ctags -R --c++-types=+px --extra=+q --excmd=pattern --exclude=Makefile --exclude=.
```

It is suggestive of C++; I cannot tell more. What is the correct command line for Haskell ctags?

UPD:

`hasktags` has been suggested. I managed to install and run it tentatively:

```
$ stack exec hasktags
Usage: hasktags [OPTION...] [files or directories...]
directories will be replaced by DIR/**/*.hs DIR/**/*.lhs
Thus hasktags . tags all important files in the current
directory.

    If directories are symlinks they will not be followed
unless you pass -L.

A special file "STDIN" will make hasktags read the line separated file
list to be tagged from STDIN.

  -c            --ctags                        generate CTAGS file (ctags)
  -e            --etags                        generate ETAGS file (etags)
  -b            --both                         generate both CTAGS and ETAGS
  -a            --append                       append to existing CTAGS and/or ETAGS file(s). Afterward this file will no longer be sorted!
                --ignore-close-implementation  ignores found implementation if it is closer than 7 lines - so you can jump to definition in one shot
  -o            --output=                      output to given file, instead of 'tags', '-' file is stdout
  -f            --file=                        same as -o, but used as compatibility with ctags
  -x            --extendedctag                 Generate additional information in ctag file.
                --cache                        Cache file data.
  -L            --follow-symlinks              follow symlinks when recursing directories
  -S[.hs,.lhs]  --suffixes[=.hs,.lhs]          list of hs suffixes including "."
  -R            --tags-absolute                make tags paths absolute. Useful when setting tags files in other directories
  -h            --help                         This help
```

There is also some path in Kate `CTags database file`:

```
/home/alexey/.local/share/kate/katectags/session_db_20171216_180641
```

I can't make much out of `hasktags` readme.

Comment: Any reason you want to use ctags instead of hasktags, which works with Haskell?

Comment: No reason at all, except for total inexperience. How am I supposed to employ `hasktags`? Is it a command line tool, or something else?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a command line tool. See the UPD. Sorry, I can't make much sense out of `hasktags` readme.

Answer (score 0):

I use hasktags and a shell function in my `.zshrc` to simplify things:

```
hasktags --ignore-close-implementation --ctags .
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm having trouble with my environment so far: Kate does not see the executable, despite it being visible from the Kate Current Project Path. For troubleshooting I need this answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852911/haskell-stack-locate-the-executable

Comment: For some reason, Kate does not look into Project for ctags executable, where it is located in my case. This is inner workings of CTags Kate plugin, though. What would happen if I just run `hasktags` manually in my project directory? Well, it runs silently, no error messages (with the suggested command line arguments), no obvious result.

Comment: Put a soft link into `/usr/local/bin`, now it runs, all wrong: The CTags program exited with code 1: hasktags: ./spaces/hehe/hehe/dbdata/mysql: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: permission denied (Permission denied). The path in the error message has nothing to do with anything. CTags inner workings again.

Comment: FWIW: The tags file generated initially by `ctags` utility with all default options weighs 205M; generated manually with `stack exec -- hasktags --ignore-close-implementation --ctags .` 1.3K. Both are text files, the latter clean and perfectly understandable. Which makes no difference functionally, though.