# Haskell, stack: locate the executable

Tags: haskell, path, executable, haskell-stack

I'm looking for something like

```
$ stack whereis hasktags
```

where `whereis` acts more or less like UNIX `whereis` command. `hasktags` is to be run like this:

```
$ stack exec -- hasktags
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stack exec -- whereis hasktags` will do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Pretty obvious in hindsight, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`stack exec -- whereis yourprogramname` works for me on a Linux box, but I have to use `stack exec -- which yourprogramname` on Mac OS X.

(`which` also works on Linux, of course.)

Note that neither of these are useful for automating deployments when the executable name is the same as one on the build machine -- not likely, but not impossible.